# Upstart stop/waiting?

Tags: boot, server, upstart

I have created a `upstart` script to start a `multicraft` daemon on system boot. Although it does start on boot, how do I stop the service? If I run `service daemonmulti stop` it returns `stop: Unknown instance:`. If I try starting it, it returns `daemonmulti stop/waiting`. Any ideas? Thanks!

My script:

```
description "Starts the multicraft daemon"
author "MythTheWolf"
start on runlevel [2345]
exec bash -c '/home/backend/multicraft/bin/multicraft start'
exec echo Daemon started at  `date` >> /var/log/testjob.log
```

Comment: Is it about Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)

Comment: 16.04 does not use `upstart`, it uses `systemd`.

Comment: I downgraded to upstart, but I will take a look.

Comment: What's the name of the Upstart job file? You can control Upstart jobs via `initctl`. To stop a job: `initctl stop <JOBNAME>`.

Comment: Also, why `exec bash -c '/home/backend/multicraft/bin/multicraft start'` and not simply `exec /home/backend/multicraft/bin/multicraft start`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Because by default, exec uses sh, not bash. I have since moved to systemd. Much better.

Comment: Not really. Upstart will use neither Bash nor Sh if the first argument is an executable and the other arguments don't contain any special characters. In that case it'll just start the executable directly.